# Need to write a autosys file watcher

Tags: java, autosys

I am pretty new to autosys. 
Need to write a autosys file watcher ...which will watch in a particular folder for a pdf file on a server A and when watcher gets any pdf on that location it will transfer that PDF file to different server B.
So i think below are the steps:
1.File watcher to continuous look at the location.
2.Autosys job to transfer file from that location to different location.

Thanks in advance for help...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried writing autosys script ,as i m totally new to autosys i was messed up in scripts.

Comment: Have you figured out how you're going to tell if a file is complete?

Comment: Well, why don't you show us what you've tried, then, so we can fix it?

Comment: If you're looking for help writing the *entire* script, this isn't the place to ask for it.  If you're stuck in a *specific* part of your script, then **post the relevant snippet** and describe what the issue is.

Comment: Below are the autosys script which i m trying to execute:

Comment: @AndrewHenle:I didnt figure out for file completion

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - it's not as easy to solve as you'd think.  Unless you integrate directly into whatever process is receiving the file (SSH, FTP, SCP, etc - and even that, that's tricky), there's no way to tell if the file is complete or only partially copied absent some sort of data from the sender.  Luckily you're receiving PDF files, which somewhere inside them have a file length, IIRC.  The reference is here:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html  You can also look at a PDF with a text editor - figuring out how to tell if it's complete should be pretty easy...

Answer (score 0):

```
Setup a Autosys Box:
insert_job: <description>_AT7_xfer_box   job_type: b
owner: root@autappq01
permission: gx,wx,we,wx
alarm_if_fail: 1

Setup a Autosys File Watcher:
insert_job: <description>_AT7_FW   job_type: f
 box_name: <description>_AT7_xfer_box
 machine: <server>
 owner: root@autappq01
 watch_file: <</filepath/filename >
 permission: gx,wx,we,wx
 watch_interval: 60
 alarm_if_fail: 1


Setup a Single Transfer:

 /* ----------------- <description>_AT7_xfer1 ----------------- */

 insert_job: <description>_AT7_xfer1   job_type: c
 box_name: <description>_AT7_xfer_box
 command: $${AT7X} $${<description>_xfer1SRC} $${<description>_xfer1DEST} $${ machine }
 machine: <server>
 owner: root@autappq01
 permission: gx,wx,we,wx
 condition: s(<description>_AT7_FW)
 std_out_file: >> /var/log/<description>_AT7.out
 std_err_file: >> /var/log/<description>_AT7.err``
 alarm_if_fail: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your concerns.I have found the solution for above problems.
Using the Autosys scripts which i have shared above.
And for the transfer from one location to another location i am using the Autosys OOTB featured AT7 transfer.